# Change header background on scroll in Wordpress Twenty Fourteen

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, navigation, onscroll

This is what I would like to see as result in WP 2014 theme:

http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ekKru

I tried to apply the same by adding the following js file and css code to my child theme:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function($) {
    var distance = 50;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > distance) {
      $('header').addClass('scrolled');
    }
    else {
      $('header').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.scrolled {
  background: #bada55;
}
```

In addition, I added the following to my functions.php in child theme:

```html
function my_custommenu_tf_child() {
 if (!is_admin()) {
 if (is_front_page()) {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'my_Custommenu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mycustommenu.js', '', '1.0', true );
 }
 }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custommenu_tf_child');
```

Did not really work...I'm not a professional developer so instead of referring to possible solutions I would appreciate if you could insert the correct code so that I can compare and see what exactly was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the code below in `.js` file?

`.scrolled {
  background: #bada55;
}`

If you have, you need to move it to some `.css` file and also linked it in your functions.php

Comment: I have it in CSS of course...not sure however how it shall be linked to the functions.php? Can you give details / code?

Comment: Here you have everything explained (with codes): https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: The easier way to add custom css would be probably use this plugin: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: OK, so I misunderstood your comment. Yes, I use child theme, I added the above css to my custom css file which is linked to the functions.php. With CSS I'm quite OK anyway, the problem must be either with the javascript code or the way I'm trying to get it work through the functions php file.